# Running powerpoint sub procedure from custom ribbon button

Tags: button, powerpoint, ribbon

I have a procedure in my ThisAddIn class (see first code block below) that I'm trying to run from the click event of a custom ribbon button that I designed using ribbon designer (see second code). I keep getting the error message: 'Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.' What do I need to do to fix this? Thanks!

First block:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Public Sub fill_textboxes(ByVal control As Office.IRibbonControl)
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                For i = 1 To Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.Count
                Application.ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(i).TextFrame.TextRange.Text = "..."
                Next
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Second block:

```
Private Sub fill_text_boxes_button_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles fill_text_boxes_button.Click

    Call ThisAddIn.fill_textboxes(fill_text_boxes_button)
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a line number associated with the error?

Comment: Yes. Line 9 which is the 'Call This AddIn.fill_textboxes(fill_text_boxes_button)

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an instance of the IRibbonControl interface to the `fill_textboxes` sub. Use the `sender` argument which represents the control which fired the event:

```
Private Sub fill_text_boxes_button_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles fill_text_boxes_button.Click

   Call ThisAddIn.fill_textboxes(sender)
End Sub
```